# BIRT - different master page header on the first page of report

Tags: birt

I need to have one **master page  header** on the first page and another **master page header** on the next pages of BIRT report.
I am using 3.7.1 version.

1. I inserted a grid with two rows to the master page header.
2. I put one new grid into each of the rows.
   First nested grid for the first page header, second nested grid for the next pages header.
3. I set an onRender scripts:

   ```
   //first nested grid
   if( pageNumber > 1 ){
   this.getStyle().display = "none";
   }
   //second nested grid
   if( pageNumber == 1 ){
   this.getStyle().display = "none";
   }else{
   this.getStyle().display = "block";
   }
   ```

This works ok with the sample database, from JDBC Data Source.
But I need XML Data Source and with that it does not work at all.
It seems as if with the sample database table, the onRender event gets called on every page, but with my XML Data Source it only gets called once.

Please, If you could help me solve this mysterious problem I would appreciated it very much.

erisa

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter what the dataSource is.  I did test it, just in case, though, and it worked for me when using an XML source.  The only thing I could think of would be that you're using auto layout and have a page break interval of 0 on your table.  Outputting to PDF would then just show the page 1 header, each time.  It wouldn't matter what dataSource you have.  You might take a look at this.

Comment: kclark posted some examples for you at http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/28949-different-master-page-header-on-the-first-page-of-report/page__pid__114846__st__0&#entry114846

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this:

P1:    Header Grid1
P2...: Header Grid2

(in your special case Grid1 is R1,R2 and Grid2 is R2 if I understand correctly)

There's a trick:

In your master page properties, tell BIRT to not display the page header on the first page and put Grid2 into the page header.

However, BIRT still reserves the *space* for the header.

Add Grid1 as the very first object to your report layout and use a *negative margin* for Grid1 to move it up accordingly.

Note: This works with the PDF emitter, but not with the Word Emitter.

Comment: BTW Yesterday I posted a patch for BIRT 4.3.2 (see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432310) which makes this work with Word Emitter, too.